# Pyspark Session Builder

Tags: python, java, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed python and java, also have installed pyspark and the everything works fine in the terminal. I am trying to build a pyspark session using python on jupyter notebook

The code I am using is

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
```

But I am Getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last) C:\Users\BINAYA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8296/4002136008.py in <module>
----> 1 spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()    
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    226                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230                     # by all sessions.

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    390         with SparkContext._lock:
    391             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 392                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    393             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    394 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in
__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
--> 146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148         except:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in
_do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    207 
    208         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210         # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211         self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyspark\context.py in
_initialize_context(self, jconf)
    327         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    328         """
--> 329         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    330 
    331     @classmethod

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)    1571     1572         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1573         return_value = get_return_value(    1574             answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)    1575 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. : java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x2e55dd0c) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x2e55dd0c    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)     at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)     at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)   at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)     at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)     at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Can someone please help me with it ?

Comment: What version of Spark and what version of Java?

Comment: "everything works fine in the terminal"  = you are able to have a spark session? If so, is your jupyter server using the same execution environment (`PATH` ` PYTHONPATH` etc) as your terminal and not some kind of virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason to build the system, you could use Docker with a ready-to-go image like https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook.

If you really want to build it from scratch, on Windows, make sure your versions match the requirements.